# ggplot y-axis values showing up as logarithmic: I want to make them linear and cut it down to 100s instead of 1000s

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am creating a dodged geom_bar which has displayed as I would like it to, however the y-axis values are showing up as logarithmic form instead of linear. I would assume because of the range of values: the high value is ~470,000 and low value is around ~40,000. I would ideally like to have the values shown as linear and then displayed in 100s as opposed to the 1000s it actually is for a cleaner look on the graph( ie showing (000s) in the subtitle). I have attached a screenshot of the graph which should hopefully clarify what I am talking about.[image: Attached Figure]

```
ggplot(Fig3.1, aes(x = `College Conference`, 
                          y = (Fig3.1$`Minute s`), 
                          fill = factor(`Regular Season Minute Type`))) +theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Comment: Could create a small sample code that includes data?

Comment: @JAQuent i have edited and put the sample of the code I used

Comment: Well, the axis isn't logarithmic, it shows the labels in scientific notation (which is different). You could probably revert the scientific notation by using `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number())`.

Comment: @teunbrand that worked perfectly, thank you for the help.